# Show that the polynomial $P = x^8-6x^3+ 2x^2+2$ is irreductible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Show that the polynomial $P = x^8-6x^3+ 2x^2+2$ is irreductible in
>   $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Is is possible to use Eisenstein's criteria? Otherwise, is anyone could help me to solve it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: $2$ is a prime which divides all but the leading coefficient of $P(x)$ and $2^2=4$ doesn't divide the constant term $2$. Hence, by Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion, $P(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$

Answer (score 2):

Recall what Eisenstein's criterion says. If you can find a prime, p, that divides all the coefficients except the leading one. And if p^2 does not divide the constant term then that polynomial is irreducible.